# Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource(path) seems to cache result. Preventable?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a Grails 2.1 application in development, and I have a service that is calling `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource(fileName)` to load a configuration file in `grails-app/conf` (I'm hoping the location doesn't matter, though).

It works just fine, **except that I have to restart the grails application to load changes** to the config file. I'd really like to be able to read the file contents *every single time* I ask for the resource, at least during development.

Also, I'd like to avoid writing my own caching system if I can avoid it. The simpler the solution, the better.

My problem seems to be similar to [this one with velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121449/getclass-getclassloader-getresourceasstream-is-caching-the-resource) but using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path).openStream()` does not seem to work.

EDIT: I think I may have left out an important detail. The resource that I am retrieving is non-static. I am using the grails template engine to inject values into the resource like so:

```
Map bindings = [keys: 'values']
new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(resource).make(bindings).toString()
```

Using my debugger, I have found that the resource text isn't changing, but knowing the above may change potential answers.

EDIT #2: I tried using URLConnection.setUseCaches(false) like so with no luck:

```
URLConnection connection = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource(path).openConnection()
connection.setUseCaches(false)
connection.connect()
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))
String content = reader.readLines().join('\n')
reader.close()
```

Comment: Not sure about the original problem you're asking about, but be very careful with new'ing up `SimpleTemplateEngine` instances.  It's possible it's been fixed, but I hit some very painful memory leakage issues with that in the past.  If I'm remembering right, it was instantiating a new class in the classloader and eventually causing the system to run out of permgen.  Caching templates that you've created is really the only way I'll use STE now.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. I'll definitely be caching the template at least in non-development envs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a resource in this manner, you might consider moving it out of grails-app/conf and into /web-app.

When running `grails run-app`, a cached version of an exploded war is actually running in a container with some outside magic monitoring various paths for changes and re-compiling and re-copying updated files similar to how one might manually hot-swap .class files and other resources.

This monitoring happens out of the box for all files in /web-app. Once the files are there, you can use the ServletContext to get a handle to the file in question. For example, you might do something like:

```
def templateFile = new File(ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('/templates/fileName.gsp')).text
```

and pass that to your templating engine. For environments that lock down the file system (e.g. Heroku), the `getRealPath` method will likely not work. You can, alternatively, use something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
def template =  IOUtils.toString(ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getResourceAsStream('/templates/fileName.gsp'), "UTF-8")
```

The downsides to this approach:

- You'll need access to the ServletContext which will require you to have a container loaded. Therefore, no unit testing on this piece of coding; you'll want an integration test instead.
- Putting resources like this in /web-app will make them public. Alternatively, you could place them in /web-app/WEB-INF if privacy is a concern.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use Spring's ResourceUtils to do this?  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html

It'd look something like ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:path/to/file.xyz")

Comment: Unfortunately, using Spring's ResourceUtils does not solve the problem. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path)` returns a URL object, so the caching is likely being performed by `URL`/`URLConnection`.

Try using [URLConnection.setDefaultUseCaches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDefaultUseCaches%28boolean%29)`(false)` when your application starts up (maybe only in dev environment for performance reasons).  This can also be set on a per-URLConnection basis with the `setUseCaches()` method.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly. Please see EDIT #2 in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but Grails services are normally singletons. If you want the file re-read on every request, you might try changing the scope to prototype.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, but I'm giving you a karmic vote because you've answered other Grails questions in other places. :)