# How to reload data from text file during runtime in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple method that reads a text file line by line and returns it as a `List<Strings>`. The problem is, if I change the file at runtime and try to call that method again it still reads the unchanged file.

Here is my code:

```
public List<String> generateStrings() throws Exception {

        InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(FILE);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<>();
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null){
            stringList.add(line);

            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        log.debug("List generated");

        return stringList;
    }
```

Is there a way to reload that file every time the method is called?

EDIT: both `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE).openStream()` and

```
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE);
if (res != null) {
    URLConnection resConn = res.openConnection();
    resConn.setUseCaches(false);
    InputStream in = resConn.getInputStream();
}
```

throws `NullPointerException`

EDIT 2:
`NullPointerException` eliminated (I had to change the path to my resource file) but it still doesn't reload the file on runtime

EDIT 3:
When I tried to fix it outside of Spring it seems that reinstantiating the whole class is working as desired but this class is injected to my service class in a constructor so I have no idea how to implement such behavior in Spring

Comment: Hi @Arkadeusz. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `getSourceAsStream` caches internally.

You can find more here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126572/1554844

Comment: I tried `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE).openStream()` as suggested in there but now it throws `NullPointerException`